# Find time-independent dynamical system equivalent to $x'=3x+(2-t)y$, $y'=xy-t$

Tags: dynamical-systems

> Given the continuous time dynamical system with the rule depending on time:
>   $$x'=3x+(2-t)y\qquad
> y'=xy-t$$
>   create a new system which is equivalent to the above system for which the rule does not depend on $t$.

---

My solution so far:
I recognize that this can be written in matrix for as in $Y'=AY$

```
|Y'| = |x'| = |3   2t| * |x|

       |y'|   |y -t/y|   |y|
```

I'm stuck here because I get the feeling my A shouldn't include any variables, so I tried to solve the DEs. I start with $y'=xy-t$:

$y'=xy-t$

$y'-xy=-t$

multiply by $u(t)=e^{-xt}$

d(y*e^-(x*t))/dt=-t*e^-(x*t)

y*e^-(x*t)=[e^(x*t)(1-x*t)]/x^2

y=[e^(2x*t)(1-x*t)]/x^2

Then I'm stuck here but I'm pretty sure this isn't the way to go.

Comment: How do you define "equivalent" here?

Comment: I believe when you take the integral of $-te^{-xt}$ you consider $x$ independent of $t$. Is this correct? Also can you explain what you mean by a rule that does not depent on $t$? As far as I understand a system of differential equations is supposed to give a solution of the form $\phi(t):=(x(t),y(t))$, which is also called a flow or a continuous dynamical system. So finding an equivalent dynamical system means to find a function $y=f(x)$ such that $\phi$ and the graph of $f$ coincide, yes?

Comment: just create another variable $z=t$, with $z'=1$. Replace all occurences of $t$ in your equations with $z$.

Comment: okay I think that I was headed in the wrong direction. I now realize that I can't separate it into y'=Ay because it is not linear, and they just want me to produce an equivalent system, so I don't think I need to do any DE solving here. I replaced all 't's with 'z's and I get the same thing ... but with z. Is that really all they're looking for ? @nonlinearism

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old, I would like to propose a solution. I believe what the question is asking is finding an equation which does not depend on t. Thus you can replace t with t=-y'+xy (obtained from second equation) in the first equation and you obtain a time independent equation.